# Progressively Measurable on a Topological Space

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

In Baldi's book, *Stochastic Calculus*, Proposition 2.1 states that a right continuous adapted process, taking values in a **topological** space $E$ will be progressively measurable.

The proof starts out in the standard way, producing a sequence of elementary processes, $X^{(n)}$, with pointwise convergence to $X$ which are progressively measurable. It concludes that as the limit of such processes, it is also progressively measurable.

But is it true that this should hold in a topological space?  Results that I am aware of on convergence of measurable functions to a measurable function are all on spaces which are at least metrizable.  In fact, there appear to be counterexamples when you do not have a metric.

Does the additional structure here (right continuity? adaptedness?) allow us to circumvent having a metric?

Or am I just parsing the book incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

If the topological space $E$ is a separable metric space, then the Borel $\sigma$-field is generated by the open balls, and Baldi's assertion is correct.

Also, the discussion here: [When are pointwise limits of measurable functions measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587155/when-are-pointwise-limits-of-measurable-functions-measurable) is instructive.  [N.B.: By a theorem of Tikhonov, a second countable regular space is metrizable.]

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I agree with your assertion.  The passage in Baldi, "Let us assume from now on that the state space $E$ is a topological space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra..."  Just curious if there's any other way out of this.